# Standard Object- Too many custom fields

Tags: custom-field, design

At the current implementation, that standard objects are customized heavily especially Account and Opportunity objects. I see many custom fields are added(about 30-40) to these objects. I was wondering is it a good a practice to add that many custom fields to an object OR add a child object to capture the custom fields?

Just wanted to get your thoughts and how you would design this..

Comment: I agree this question could be improved. However I answered because I think there are peculiarities around storage and limits that are worthy of being discussed. It isn't just, should I add a column to a table, there are hidden implications that should be considered when designing. Maybe @sfdc_king you could improve the question so as to not invite opinion as much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pretty complex answer, and can often depend on your implementation goals. But here are a few reasons why you might pick to add more fields or new objects:

**Object Limits**

I big reason why customers avoid creating a new child object is the limit to the number of allowed custom objects. This is often tied to your salesforce contract or edition, so optimizing how many objects is often a design-time decision.

**Fat Objects Efficiency**

Record storage is calculated on a *per row* basis. Apart from a few standard objects a single record counts as 2k of storage against your org's limit. This makes for some very simple math to determine how many records you can store. For example, a DE org comes with 5MB of data storage. So you will be able to store approximately 2500 records. This is the same whether your object has 2 fields, or 200 fields. So sometimes the "fat object" strategy is employed purely for the purpose of saving record storage space.

I've had to do this where I was storing sensor measurements on a 15 minute basis. In order to conserve space, I made each row a day, and each column the 15 minute period where the measurement was observed. This would have been really weird in any other data source, but it allowed me to optimize my space in this unusual instance.

**The Emergent Org**

There are plenty of times where the number of fields in an object is purely down to bad change management procedures and lack of governance, awareness or documentation as to what has been built before. Someone says they need some data about their account records. They tell the person with the keys to the data model. That person builds it. Requestor is happy. Another user makes a same or similar request and the process is repeated. This unhappy circumstance is not just limited to fields on objects but can also lead to a blob-like org in many ways (too many sharing rules, roles, profiles, reports, to name a few).

**Normalize Where Possible**

As a general rule you want to follow good data design practices. Attempt to normalize where possible. Make compromises where you must. But try to avoid the emergent org problem.